# I was told not to use apt-get install in a setup.sh script

Tags: 18.04, init

What should I be using? Are there any standard formats/design patterns for setup.sh scripts?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that claim ? Did you mean `apt` and not `apt-get` because IIRC the former was design to be interactive, whilst the latter is suitable for script uses.

Comment: FYI: You've tagged `init` ?  but have tagged you're using a systemd release (ie. 18.04) ?  init scripts likely aren't what you want? so why tag it?